# WebDriverWait behave like it doesn't wait

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I'm getting an exception

`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element`

Although I'm using WebDriverWait for 10 seconds, it throws exception very fast (almost immidiatly).. like it doesn't wait. At all.

```
var waitForElement10Sec = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

waitForElement10Sec.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("myForm")));
```

This is a div which is a wrapper for an input checkbox. All these tags rendered after another button click, then I try to wait before continue. First I tried to wait for the checkbox itself to be clickable but got the same excpetion, so then tried to wait for his parent.

```
waitForElement10Sec.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("myChkbox"))).Click();
```

Note - sometimes it success, sometimes it doesn't. I can't point on a cause or different.

I'm using latest nuget package,

- .NET framework 4.6
- Chrome v108

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following extension method which works for me;

```cs
internal static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this ChromeDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan timeout)
        => FindElement((IWebDriver)driver, by, timeout);

    public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan pollingInterval = default)
    {
        // NOTE Also see: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

        var webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
        {
            // Will default to the DefaultWait polling interval of selenium which is as of writing half a second
            PollingInterval = pollingInterval
        };

        // We're polling the dom, so this is normal procedure and not an exception.
        webDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));

        return webDriverWait
            .Until(drv => drv.FindElement(@by));
    }
}
```

Try that out. The key here is that you ignore the exception and just loop untill the element can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not share all your Selenium code and not a link to the page you are working on we can only guess...
So, since simetimes it works and sometimes not there are several possible issues that can cause that:

1. Your internet connection is too slow or the page you working on is too slow etc. Try increasing the timeout from 10 to 30 seconds.
2. The element may be on the edge of visible veiwport (screen area detected as visible) - try scrolling that element into the view.

There are more possible issues, but we need to debug your actual code to give better answer

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Both issues you're mentioned sounds possibly, but if I give it 10 seconds timeout, it doesn't mean it should wait the whole 10 seconds? Like I wrote in my original post, it throws exception almost immidiatly, much before 10 seconds are passed

Comment: WebDriverWait is polling the DOM every 500 milliseconds or something else until it finds the matching condition or till the timeout. SO, in case element is there and it is visible - the code will continue immediatly after finding that element, will not wait untill the timeout. But if no such element there - it will wait until the defined timeout and then throw the exception.

Comment: This is how WebDriverWait works. It should not throw exception immediatelly. In case it does - you made something wrong. I don't know what. Maybe you mixing implicit wait with WebDriverWait ?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I didn't set any timeout except the waitDriver. And it throws me away right and it come to the line `until`, for sure not wait 10 seconds or even 5 sec, but I will try to increase it